# Start application non-elevated from NSIS installer

Tags: windows-vista, installation, nsis

I have an NSIS installer, that gives the option "Run program now" when the installation has completed successfully.

The installer runs elevated (as administrator) on Vista, but as a result, my installed program will also run elevated when started immediately from the installer. This gives a problem with certain 3rd party software I'm using inside my app.

How can I prevent the application from being run elevated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your best option is to just disable/hide the run checkbox when running on >=NT6 (Same issue exists on NT5 also, but most people don't use runas, so you probably don't care as much)
- The other option is to use the [UAC plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in)